# rails How to calculate time difference with integer between 3 dates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

How to compare 3 dates, (Time.now - @model.updated_at) < :integer(converted to days) , So first is a substraction between two dates and the difference between the two dates as (amount of time) is compared(< less than) to an :integer.days(amount of time). Hope this makes sense... im going through different options but im just getting more confused. Thanks for any help.

```
"#{Time.now}".to_i.days - "#{:updated_at}".to_i.days < "#{:integer}".to_i.days
```

Comment: I was getting many errors that I thought were because of my :integer but turned out to be because of the two date difference. Not sure why but Time diffrence gem suggested solved the issue. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have also faced the same scenario in one of my projects and there i used the [Time Difference Gem](https://github.com/tmlee/time_difference) . It is very simple and easy to integrate and provides you additional helper methods to get the difference in year, month, week, day, hour, minute, and seconds.

Set the start and end date

```
start_time = Time.new(2013,1)
end_time = Time.new(2014,1)
```

Now call the calculate the difference as

```
TimeDifference.between(start_time, end_time).in_days
=> 365.0
```

Additionally it provides you liberty to fetch all differences at the same time

```
TimeDifference.between(start_time, end_time).in_each_component
=> {:years=>1.0, :months=>12.0, :weeks=>52.14, :days=>365.0, :hours=>8760.0, :minutes=>525600.0, :seconds=>31536000.0}
```

Comment: There is no need to add a new dependency for this.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti, there is no need to shut down the possibility of adding a new dependency, it all depends on the project, how often this differences are calculated and how easier it makes the code to read.

Comment: If you have ever worked on big projects, you understand the importance of keeping a low number of external dependencies. So yes, in this case it's doesn't make sense at all to add an external dependency to a gem when you can accomplish the same task with what you have.

Comment: But I have, and I'm just saying never say never. There are use cases for this "helper" gems. At least we agree that the developer should be conscious when introducing new dependencies.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Rails, you can get the difference in seconds between two time objects using

```
time1 - time2
```

For example:

```
diff = 3.days.ago - Time.current
# -259200.000132
```

Use `to_i` to get the integer difference.

```
diff.to_i
-259200
```

The value is in seconds. Hence to get the days simply use:

```
((5.days.ago - 1.day.ago).to_i / 86400).abs
# => 4
```

Comment: I think you have the day in seconds value wrong: `1.day.to_i # => 86400`, that give the correct result of 4. Other way: `((5.days.ago - 1.day.ago).to_i / 1.day).abs #=> 4`

Comment: Thanks @Leito, that was a typo

Answer (score 0):

I like to use the gem time_diff

You can use

[github](https://github.com/abhidsm/time_diff)

Here is a example how it works

```
Time.diff(Time.parse('2011-03-06'), Time.parse('2011-03-07'))
# => {:year => 0, :month => 0, :week => 0, :day => 1, :hour => 0, :minute => 0, :second => 0, :diff => '1 day and 00:00:00'}
```

the difference can match with the third_date